# How can I have an atomic block of code that doesn't access the database in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, atomic

I am working on a project that uses `Django` and `Django REST Framework`. In one of the views there's a method `F()` that does the following:

1. Fetches data from the database (read operation)
2. Sends a create (POST) request to a 3rd party API. (although not local, this is a write operation and this is where a race condition might take place)
3. Returns JSON data

I'd like `F()` to be atomic, in other words, if the server receives multiple requests at the same time asking for this view, the server should handle one request at a time and not allow multiple threads to access this block of code simultaneously. How can this be achieved? I have read that `Django` provides `transactions.atomic()` but this guarantees atomicity of database transactions, what I need is atomicity for a whole block of code regardless of whether it accesses the database or not.

Answer (score 2):

The concept you are looking for is a "mutex" or a "lock". This article may guide you in the right direction https://lincolnloop.com/blog/distributed-locking-django/

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look into this, but I'll wait for other answers in case this is possible to achieve without using 3rd party libraries/frameworks